# javascript Radio bootstrap v3.3.7

Tags: javascript, php, radio-button

[the problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De52X.png)

i am working on a quiz script i have a problem when i load the answers 
it came as javascript radio but when i choose one of them then i go to another choice the old one still highlighted!!

```
<?php
while ($question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_question)) {
    $no ++;
    $sql_answer = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `answers` WHERE `question_id` = '$question[question_id]' AND `category` = 'listening' AND `answer` != '' ORDER BY rand()");
?>
<?php
    $question_html = '<b>'.$no.') '.$question['question'].'</b>';
    $ans_no='';
    while ($answer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_answer)){
        $ans ='
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default btn btn-default">
                <input type="radio" name="question'.$question['question_id'].'" value = "'.$answer['correct'].'" id="option2" autocomplete="off" > '.$answer['answer'].'
                    </label>
            </div>';
        $ans_no .=$ans;
    }
?>
<?php

    $vowels = '[*answer*]';

    $onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "$ans_no", "$question_html");
    ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style=" margin-top:3px;margin-bottom: 3px;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php
            echo $onlyconsonants;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" onclick="stopload();">Submit the Answers</a>
```

Comment: Show us your html output, not your php code. I think it has something to do with your input name attributes (I am pretty sure that every radio button has unique name).

Answer (score 0):

the problem that i was looping the Radio bootstrap so the browser see the radio options carpet
here is the right code

```
<?php
                        $question_html = '<b>'.$no.') '.$question['question'].'</b>';
                        $ans_no='<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">';
                        while ($answer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_answer)){
                            $ans ='
                                                  <label class="btn btn-default btn btn-default">
                                                    <input type="radio" name="question'.$question['question_id'].'" value = "'.$answer['correct'].'" id="option2" autocomplete="off" > '.$answer['answer'].'
                                                                                                    </label>
                                                ';
                            $ans_no .=$ans;
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php
```